# Getting access to individual area elements with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to modify the focus+ context example to study the blackbody spectrum with my students.

http://bl.ocks.org/1667367

The problem is that for me the only way to color segment is to plot bar colored charts.

I'd like to do it with the area generator, like this I can have all the benefits of the interpolation when I zoom on.

I can't access to each area element to fill it in the rgb color I want.

**Is there any way to acces to the individual area elements and fill it with a function?**

Here's my files with an orange filled area(focus) that I'd like to color as I do with the bar chart(context).

http://bl.ocks.org/4345931

In advance thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the right approach here is to use a `linearGradient` element ([specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html)). You can see my implementation here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/JZACC/

The main point here is that instead of drawing each color as a separate element, you define a gradient of spectrum colors and apply the same gradient to both the area and the context bar:

```
// set up gradient elements
var gradient = defs.append('linearGradient')
    .attr('id', 'spectrumGradient');

// set up gradient scale
var gx = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 1]);
```

Then, when the data is loaded, you create `stop` elements for each color:

```
// update gradient scale
gx.domain(x.domain());
// create gradient
gradient.selectAll('stop')
    // remove duplicates
    .data(data)
  .enter().append('stop')
    .attr('offset', function(d) { return gx(d.wl); })
    .attr('stop-color', toRGB);
```

And apply it using `url(#id)` notation:

```
focus.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .attr("d", area)
  .attr('fill', 'url(#spectrumGradient)');
```

Comment: **Thank you for this rapid answer**, it is a really nice approach, which preserve the fact that the area is a unique path

Comment: I wasn't searching in the right direction. I'll need a little more time to understand all the subtleties of this great library.

Comment: Glad it helped. FYI - if you think this is the "right" answer (not that there's only one right answer in this case), you can mark it correct by clicking on the checkmark to the left.

Comment: I marked it correct, it works perfectly and I'll experiment this usage of gradients in other plots. **Thank you for sharing your knowledge**